# Time difference of hours and minutes

Tags: oracle

I am trying to find out the time difference in hours and minutes but getting error, Please help to find out the query , For example I need answer of below in oracle
16:55- 14:00 = 2:55

Comment: What is the datatype of the two values to start with?

Comment: Please show the query and the error.

Comment: Do you have to cover differences > 24 hours?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the times to a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and then subtract one from the other to get an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type; then use `EXTRACT` to get the hour and minute components and format them:

```sql
SELECT start_time,
       end_time,
       TO_CHAR( EXTRACT( HOUR FROM difference ), 'FM00' )
         || ':'
         || TO_CHAR( ABS( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM DIFFERENCE ) ), 'FM00' )
         AS difference
FROM   (
  SELECT start_time,
         end_time,
         ( TO_DATE( end_time, 'HH24:MI' ) - TO_DATE( start_time, 'HH24:MI' ) ) DAY TO SECOND
           AS difference
  FROM   test_data
)
```

Which, for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( start_time, end_time ) AS
  SELECT '14:00', '16:55' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '14:50', '15:23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '16:00', '14:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '16:00', '14:20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '00:00', '23:59' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> START_TIME | END_TIME | DIFFERENCE
> :--------- | :------- | :---------
> 14:00      | 16:55    | 02:55     
> 14:50      | 15:23    | 00:33     
> 16:00      | 14:00    | -02:00    
> 16:00      | 14:20    | -01:40    
> 00:00      | 23:59    | 23:59
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e0ff96e1488a6f55c151175eeb0d5c2a)*

Answer (score 0):

Please see below

```
SELECT 
  substr(
     to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP ('16:55', 'HH24:MI') - 
         TO_TIMESTAMP ('14:00', 'HH24:MI'), 
         'HH24:MI')
     ,12
     ,5) "Hours"
FROM 
   DUAL;
          
SELECT 
  to_number(substr(
    to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP ('16:55', 'HH24:MI') - 
            TO_TIMESTAMP ('14:00', 'HH24:MI'), 
            'HH24:MI')
    ,12
    ,2))
   +
  to_number(substr(
    to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP ('16:55', 'HH24:MI') - 
            TO_TIMESTAMP ('14:00', 'HH24:MI'), 
            'HH24:MI')
    ,15
    ,2))/60 "Decimal Hours"    
FROM 
  DUAL;
```

Output

```
Hours
-----
02:55


Decimal Hours
-------------
   2.91666667
```

Comment: This will always return a positive value, even if the start time is after the end time [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b1ab31d0792ab369b4920dda71afa7c).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your two times are strings, you can use a query like the one below to calculate the difference between the times. By casting time strings to dates, you can then subtract them from each other and convert the result into the format that you want.

#### Query

```sql
WITH
    times (start_time, end_time)
    AS
        (SELECT '14:00', '16:55' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '5:00', '3:00' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '7:00', '23:45' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '15:00', '03:20' FROM DUAL)
SELECT start_time,
       end_time,
          TRUNC (
                (  TO_DATE ('1-JAN-2000 ' || end_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
                 - TO_DATE ('1-JAN-2000 ' || start_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'))
              * 24)
       || ':'
       || RPAD (
              ABS (
                  TRUNC (
                        (  (  (  TO_DATE ('1-JAN-2000 ' || end_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
                               - TO_DATE ('1-JAN-2000 ' || start_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'))
                            * 24)
                         - TRUNC (
                                 (  TO_DATE ('1-JAN-2000 ' || end_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
                                  - TO_DATE ('1-JAN-2000 ' || start_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'))
                               * 24))
                      * 60)),
              2,
              '0')    AS difference
  FROM times;
```

#### Result

```
   START_TIME    END_TIME    DIFFERENCE
_____________ ___________ _____________
14:00         16:55       2:55
5:00          3:00        -2:00
7:00          23:45       16:45
15:00         03:20       -11:40
```

Comment: If you have the start and end times `15:00` and `03:20` respectively then the output is `-11:-4` when it should be `-11:40`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7db5e915d592c5abb14bbcf2774dd980)

Comment: Thanks @MT0. I added `ABS` to correct the issue.